# How Does Rails 3's "data-method='delete'" Degrade Gracefully?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript, graceful-degradation

Rails 3 does some cool stuff to make Javascript unobtrusive, so they've done things like this:

```
= link_to "Logout", user_session_path, :method => :delete
```

..converts to

```
<a href="/logout" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Logout</a>
```

But it just occurred to me.. When I turn off javascript the method isn't DELETE anymore, it's GET as expected.  So are there plans to, or is there some way to, allow these `data-` attributes to degrade gracefully, so that link still is a DELETE request?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The change they made in Rails 3 with these `data-` attributes wasn't about graceful degradation, it was about unobtrusive JavaScript.

In Rails 2, specifying `:method => :delete` on a link would generate a whole bunch of inline JavaScript that would create a form with a hidden input and then submit the form. That was the same as it is now: turn off JavaScript and it defaults to a GET request. As such, supporting the case of no JavaScript is the same as it was before.

One option is to use a form/button instead of a link so you can include the method as a hidden field, much like the Rails 2 JavaScript does. Another option is to have the GET version take you to an intermediate page which in turn has the form/button.

The benefit of the new approach is that it's unobtrusive. The JavaScript for changing the HTTP verb exists in an external file and uses the `data-` attributes to determine which elements it should be attached to.

Answer (score 21):

Rather than using the `link_to` method -- which would require you use JavaScript to ensure that the HTTP method is `DELETE` -- use the `button_to` method, which will create a form with a hidden input element which tells Rails to treat the HTTP method as `DELETE` rather than `POST`. If necessary, you can then use CSS to style the button in the form so that it looks like a link.

Comment: This worked for me when the link itself was loaded after the fact via JavaScript, preventing Rails from replacing it with the form. I presume `button_to` worked because it turns it into a form on the Ruby side of things instead of with JavaScript after the page is loaded. I'd never heard of `button_to` before, so thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The only chance you have is define a form. A link can't be a POST with _method="delete" without Javascript or by form.

Comment: it can have query string ?_method=delete

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible without javascript.

I make a small jQuery plugin for converting `data-method` link attribute to pseudo hidden forms (used in laravel project for example).

If you want to use it : https://github.com/Ifnot/RestfulizerJs