# Linking to a page with a specific HTTP Method (DELETE)

Tags: html, http

How can I link to a page and make the browser call it with the DELETE method, as Rails does?
I tried `<a href="DELETE /post?id=3">DELETE ME</a>`but doesn`t work.
I use Node.js, so I can use it to handle DELETE method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. Links will only ever trigger a GET request.

You can choose between a GET and a POST in a form.

Other HTTP request types can be made using JavaScript and XMLHttpRequest, but not reliably cross-browser.

Comment: With some javascript magic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809200/how-does-rails-3s-data-method-delete-degrade-gracefully

Comment: rails can only handle them if they come.. but a link in a browser can not produce it yet.. jquery.ajax() method can

Answer (score 2):

You can use a javascript plugin like [RestfulizerJs](https://github.com/Ifnot/RestfulizerJs) for converting your links to pseudo forms.