# Why @GetMapping instead of @DeleteMapping for deleting works in Controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapping, thymeleaf

I have a simple webapp showing list of students with add and delete button like this: 
[image]

**index.html - table**

```html
<tr th:each="student : ${students}">
     <td th:text="${student.firstName} + ' ' + ${student.lastName}"></td>
     <td th:text="${student.email}"></td>
     <td th:text="${student.department}"></td>
     <td><a th:href="@{/delete/{id}(id=${student.id})}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

**IndexController.java - for deleting**

```java
@GetMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteStudent(@PathVariable Long id)
    {
        studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

My question - why it has to be `@GetMapping` in my controller that will delete a student using Delete button on the www page? When I had `@DeleteMapping` there (as I thought it should be) I couldn't delete a student with Delete button on the www page. There was a `405 error` while doing it but via Postman with delete method selected I could delete it.

Comment: Because the delete button is simply a link that is styled to look like a button. Links always requested using GET method.

Comment: I think you can add `method="delete"` to your `a` tag. The default is a get request.

Comment: You can use something other than GET for links??https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926512/how-to-specify-delete-method-in-a-link-or-form

Comment: Ok now I understand, links = get method by default. Thx for answers.

Comment: As a side note: if you already trying to use `HTTP DELETE` word, there's no use in having `/delete/` as part of the URI on top of that, you should just go for `@Delete("{id}")`.

Answer (score 1):

@DeleteMapping annotation needs a **th: method = "delete"** to work.

```
<td>
      <form  th: action = "@ {/delete/{id}(id=${student.id})}"  th: method = "delete" >
      <input  class = "btn btn-default btn-xs"  type = "submit" = Valeur "Supprimer"  /> 
      </ form> 
</td>
```

Comment: use href instead of input like this to submit form :  <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()">Supprimer</a>