# Link to remote with <i> tag sending direct request instead of ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, button, twitter-bootstrap

I have a strange problem .
I am using twitter bootstrap btn, btn-primary along with custom defined icon class just like their gliphicon.

Sample Code is below

```
<a href="send/path" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Sending..." data-remote="true" style="float:none;"><i class="icon-send margin-right-5"></i>Send</a>
```

When i click exactly on the text (ie Send) in the button it sends ajax request.
But when i click on the icon in the button it sends direct request.
If the same button is loaded via ajax . both works fine.

I dont know why the browser sending a direct request overriding the data-remote function which the jquery rails javascript defines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up writing a action helper along with a javascript functon to send an ajax request using jquery.ajax

```
 def ajax_button_tag(url, text, button_html={}, icon_html={})
        icon_html[:class] = "margin-right-5" unless icon_html[:class] 
        icon_html[:class] = icon_html[:class] + " margin-right-5" unless (icon_html[:class] && icon_html[:class].match("margin-right-5"))
        icon_html_tag = raw("<i #{icon_html.map{|k,v| "#{k}=\"#{v}\""}.join()} ></i>")
        raw("<button #{button_html.map{|k,v| "#{k}=\"#{v}\""}.join()} onclick=\"sendAjaxRequest('#{url}');\">#{icon_html_tag}#{text}</button>")
      end

function sendAjaxRequest(path, mname){
    method_type = mname || "GET";
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: method_type,
        dataType: "script",
        url: path
    });
}

<%= ajax_button_tag('/path/to/resource', {:class=>"btn btn-primary", :remote=>true, 'data-loading-text'=>'updating...'}, {:class=>'icon-save icon-white'})%>
```

Answer (score 0):

This  element. Is it floated or absolutely positoned? This may lead your browser to handle it differently.

Try assigning it `display: inline-block`  instead of floats or positions and see if that makes the problem go away.

Alternatively, you could bind the javascript function to the child `<i>` element as well as the `<a>` and see if that helps.

Comment: how will i bind the onclick function of the parent a tag to the i tag ?