# Rails 3 Submit Tag + html_safe

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html-sanitizing, font-awesome, html-safe

What's wrong with this line of code?

```
<%= submit_tag "Delete <i class='icon-check'></i>".html_safe, :disable_with => "Deleting", :class => "btn btn-danger"%>
```

This literally produces:

[image]

Evidently my html_safe call isn't doing anything.

**Background:**

I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) as well as [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) and I'm essentially trying to achieve a submit button with an icon inside of it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To extend on Lukas' answer I needed a button tag rather than an input. This code produced the effect I was looking for:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
    Delete <i class="icon-check"></i> 
</button>
```

Which resulted in:

[image: result]

I found the answer I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376192/add-icon-to-submit-button-in-twitter-bootstrap-2).

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with it? Submit button values should not contain embedded HTML code.

This is how submit button looks in HTML:

`<input type="submit" value="Submit" />`

HTML tags in `value` attributes are interpreted as text, not as HTML:

`<input type="submit" value="<i>Submit</i>" />`

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= form.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-success' do %>
     <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Funder <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
<% end %>
```

This is good answer.