# how to put icon in rails submit button

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and want to put an icon in the submit button for a form.
here is the code:

```
<%= f.submit "Submit for Approval <i class='icon-share-alt icon-white'></i>", 
                                class: "button_green" %>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit for Approval &lt;i class='icon-share-alt icon-white'&gt;&lt;/i&gt;" name="commit" class="button_green">
```

I tried adding both raw and html_safe to the text but neither one seemed to work.
I know one solution would be to have the class be an image with the icon in it already but I would like to do this without creating additional images/css. any suggestions?

Comment: This is a client-side problem solved via CSS. Please show your client-side code, not your Rails code.

Comment: i am specifically asking if there is a way to do this with rails/erb. i want the generated html to include the icon in the button text, not using css or additional images

Comment: I'm no Rails expert, but that HTML should generate an icon if Bootstrap is included properly. Looks like a Rails issue.

Comment: Ok...then show the HTML!

Comment: this is the html that gets generated
`<input type="submit" value="Submit for Approval &lt;i class='icon-share-alt icon-white'&gt;&lt;/i&gt;" name="commit" class="button_green">`

Comment: See [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12078262/1684247).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can do this by using the button_tag instead:

```
<%= button_tag( :class => "button_green") do %>
  Submit for Approval <i class="icon-share-alt icon-white"></i>
<% end %>
```

This will create a `<button type="submit"></button>` element with the icon and wordage inside. I've tested and it works. The default action for `button_tag` is to submit, so if you need a different action (like cancel for example), you can use the `:type => "button"` option to override the default submit behavior.

Edit: For Bootstrap 3, the icon class names have changed, so you would put

```
<span class="glyphicon-white glyphicon-share-alt white"></span>
```

Notice, there is no longer a special class for white icons. Just make a css class `.white` and put `color: #fff;`. Simple. You can use any color or text style you like, since the icons are now a font.

Related Question: [Add Icon to Submit Button in Twitter Bootstrap 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376192/add-icon-to-submit-button-in-twitter-bootstrap-2?rq=1), and [How do I change Bootstrap 3's glyphicons to white?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070322/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3s-glyphicons-to-white)

Comment: I don't like this solution because it doesn't make use of the f variable... though the result is probably the same.

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris - My answer addresses this.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer (making use of Rails' `f` variable) is:

```
<%= f.button nil, class: "button_green" do %>
    Submit for Approval <i class="icon-share-alt icon-white"></i>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Both this and the accepted answer are correct. It's a matter whether you instantiate your form with or without a block: `<%= form_with model: @post do |form| %>` vs `<%= form_with(model: @post, url: super_posts_path) %>`

Answer (score -1):

```
.button_green {
   background-image:url(...your image path...);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   padding-left:30px;
}
```

You may need to adjust the padding to match the size of the icon.