# How do I change Bootstrap 3's glyphicons to white?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I've got the glyphicons in my page, but they are black. How do I set the glyphicons to white?

Comment: glyphicons is font, not image. so you can use css font property to style it. (include color, rotate, zoom). y

Comment: This question was incorrectly marked as a duplicate (or at least pointed to a question that is not a duplicate). This question refers to bootstrap-3 where the icons are represented by the glyphicons font (not an image asset). The question referred to by the duplicate flag refers to older bootstrap which used images for icons. While it mentions many alternatives it never succinctly answered this specific question sufficiently that I would call a duplicate. I found the accepted answer here simplistically helpful.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can just create your own `.white` class and add it to the glyphicon element.

```css
.white, .white a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home white"></i>
```

Comment: @kba: Admittedly, I don’t use Bootstrap, but [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#glyphicons) → [Glyphicons for Bootstrap](http://glyphicons.getbootstrap.com/) → [repository](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-glyphicons) → [webfonts](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-glyphicons/blob/gh-pages/less/bootstrap-glyphicons.less). Seems to check out.

Comment: I am talking about Bootstrap 3. Bootstrap 3 uses glyphicons, while Bootstrap 2 uses icon. I found out anyway. I placed it into a <li>, in which it inherited the css of it.

Comment: I did a similar thing, but gave the CSS class a bootstrap-esque name 'glyphicon-inverse' instead.

Comment: All glyphicons have an inverse. That is, another icon which is opposite color (black & white). CSS seems superfluous in my eyes.

Comment: It may be better to make the CSS selector `.glyphicon.white` for specificity, etc.