# Change the color of glyphicons to blue in some- but not at all places using Bootstrap 2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using the Bootstrap framework for my UI. I want to change the color of my glyphicons to blue, but not in all places. In some places it should use the default color.

I have referred to these two links, but I am not finding anything helpful.

- [Can I add color to bootstrap icons only using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379153/can-i-add-color-to-bootstrap-icons-only-using-css)
- [How do I change Bootstrap 3's glyphicons to white?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070322/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3s-glyphicons-to-white)

Please note: I am using **Bootstrap 2.3.2**.

Comment: UPDATE: for BS4 just add 'text-primary' to the class of the icon.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally I found answer myself. To add new icons in 2.3.2 bootstrap we have to add [Font Awsome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) css in you file. After doing this we can override the styles with css to change the color and size.

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

CSS

```
.brown{color:#9b846b}
```

If we want change the color of icon then just add brown class and icon will turn in brown color. It also provide icon of various size.

HTML

```
<p><i class="icon-camera-retro icon-large brown"></i> icon-camera-retro</p> <!--brown class added-->
<p><i class="icon-camera-retro icon-2x"></i> icon-camera-retro</p>
<p><i class="icon-camera-retro icon-3x"></i> icon-camera-retro</p>
<p><i class="icon-camera-retro icon-4x"></i> icon-camera-retro</p>
```

Comment: Newer versions (4.0.3 at the time of this comment) are available at http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/#fontawesome_tab

Answer (score 291):

The icon will adopt the color from value of the `color` css property of it's parent.

You can either add this directly to the style:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color:blue"></span>
```

Or you can add it as a class to your icon and then set the font color to it in CSS

HTML

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user blue"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
```

CSS

```
.blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S3R23/) has an example.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Bootstrap /2.3.2/.It is not working for me.

Comment: Still you can use it, delete all the css rules for glyphicon and add this css file http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css and download the glyphicon fonts from bootstrap 3, this will workout.

Comment: @VikasGhodke, that would still require migration of the whole project to version 3.

Answer (score 203):

Simply apply Twitter Bootstrap 
`text-success` class on Glyphicon:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play text-success">начал работу</span>
```

[image]

Full list of available colors: [Bootstrap Documentation: Helper classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/) 
(Blue is present also)

Comment: why to mix oranges with apples? :\

Comment: * `начал работу` is `started a work`. I'd writen the answer on fly and I did not thought that it would be voted high.  Thus the screenshot was made in russian from my previous app to show how the markup looked.

Comment: I find it very appropriate if the icon must be shown exacly because there have been a success in the operation.

Comment: This is better because the color applied will conform to the current Bootstrap theme color scheme

Comment: @naXa try `text-danger`. Here's a [full list](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/) of colours.

Comment: @naXa ty! I fixed the link!

Answer (score 7):

You can do this as well, hopeit helps

```
<span style="color:black"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></i></span>
```

Answer (score 7):

For bootstrap 3.0, this worked for me:

```
.myclass .glyphicon {color:blue !important;}
```

Answer (score 3):

I created an alternate [colors library for bootstrap 2.3.2](http://www.devlifeline.com/2013/09/twitter-bootstrap-glyphicons-extended.html) it's available and simple to use for anyone interested in more colors for the old glyphicons library.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can set the icons to the white color. 
here is how it worked for me.

`Bootstrap <3`

### HTML

```
<i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>
```

This would make your icon appear white.

Comment: The `icon-white` worked for me with Bootstrap 2. The question asked for blue, but knowing there's a single class for white seems handy.

Answer (score 3):

If it is only a bootstrap icon. Note that icons are under text or rather typography. Just add the text color class like this. E.g text-primary, text-info and so on and so forth to the icon class:

```
<i class="icon features-icon icons8-collaboration-2 text-primary"></i>
<i class="icon features-icon icons8-collaboration-2 text-secondary"></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap >= v4.0 dropped glyphicon support

> Dropped the Glyphicons icon font. If you need icons, some options are:
>
> the upstream version of [Glyphicons](https://glyphicons.com/)
>
> [Octicons](https://octicons.github.com/)
>
> [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/)

Source: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#components

If you are using Bootstrap >= v4.0 or newer, you can use existing style classes of bootstrap such as `text-success`,`text-warning` etc.

For example, if you are using fontawesome:

```
<i class="fa fa-tag text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
.blue-icon{
color:blue !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<i class="fa fa-wrench blue-icon"></i>
```

Glyphicons are removed in 4.0, i recommend Font-awesome 4 or newer :)

Answer (score 1):

All previous answers are correct but here is a simple and quick way if you only need one icon in one place to change it's color:

```
   <p style="color:green">Time icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" ></span></p>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Color not work, if you use for bootstrap font png image, as i.

```
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  *margin-right: .3em;
  line-height: 14px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
  background-position: 14px 14px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

HTML5 use css filter to colorize image, example

```
filter: invert(100%)  contrast(2) brightness(50%) sepia(40%) saturate(450%) hue-rotate(-50deg);
```