# How to change bootstrap icon colour to yellow?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am using bootstrap 2.3.2. in my app. I am using bootstrap icons and wanted to change the default colour. I found answers from this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379153/can-i-add-color-to-bootstrap-icons-only-using-css) but I dont know how to change it yellow colour.I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334851/bootstrap-change-the-color-of-glyphicons-to-blue-but-not-at-all-palces) also but I wanted to change like [this](http://bootply.com/105784)

Comment: Recolour the sprite PNG file and assign a new class.

Comment: `Please the bootply?`

Comment: @BenMSorry its update

Comment: You can change the bg http://bootply.com/105793 but if you want the image color you may need an image editor.

Comment: @Danko Thanks for your comment.Well image editor means photoshop?

Comment: Yep like photoshop is very simple to change replacing color or adjusting tones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend Font Awesome for what you're looking for:

[Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/)

Comment: Thanks for answering.Well I am using bootstrap netcdna so how to change the colour using the link you provided

Comment: Include the following in your page <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">.  You should then be able to use CSS to change the style such as how it's done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474452/can-i-change-the-color-of-font-awesomes-icon-color

Comment: Thanks again.Well I am new to this.Can you give me a fiddle or can you please update the bootply that I have provided in the question.I just need one example and the rest I will do myself