# Bootstrap icon not displaying?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I am using bootstrap 3 and trying to add a bootstrap icon i.e. "icon-list" but it isn't working. I have added height and width to it but it doesn't display though it still loads in page but not visible.

But "icon-bar" is working without any issue.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <h3><i class="icon-list"></i>Lorel Ipsum</h3>
                                    <p>Dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            1234
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the built in glyphicons?  Those need to be used in a span according to the bootstrap docs.  I.e.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-class-name"></span>
```

Comment: Alright this works. What if i want to change its color to white and add a blue circle to the background.

Comment: Something similar was mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334851/bootstrap-change-the-color-of-glyphicons-to-blue-but-not-at-all-palces