# Cant get a Facebook glyphicon in front of the text

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a website were I can login with a Facebook account, The only problem I get right now is that I can't get the glyphicon from Facebook in front of my text in the button. Down here you see the code. I am using Bootstrap too,

```
<input type="button"onclick="window.location = '<?php echo $loginURL ?>';"
class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook" value="Login met Facebook">
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: the button]

And I want to get something like this:

[image: fucture facebook button]

I know you need to use a span class but I can't get it to work in the same button, if I use the span I get the icon but not in the same button but under or above it.

---

This is the code I got now and it looks the way I want it to but now the link doesnt work.. So I press the button but nothing happens..

```
<button onclick="window.location = '<?php echo $loginURL ?>';" 
class="btn btn-md" style="background-color:#3b5998; color:white; width:100%;">
<span class="fa fa-facebook mr-2"></span> Sign in with Facebook
```

The code down below is the code that works but doesnt look the way I want..

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location = '<?php echo $loginURL ?>';"
value="Login met Facebook" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook">
```

Comment: try `<button><span class="fa-facebook"></span> Sign in with Facebook</button>`

Comment: That didnt work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two solutions.

1. change the **`<input>`** Element into the **`<button>`** element.
   (Easy Solution)
2. you have to use the **`::before` CSS selector**, This requires changing the `Font-Family` to Font-Awesome font and put the correct **unicode** into the `content` CSS property. (Toughest)

**Easiest Solution:**

- change the **`<input>` Element** into **`<button>` Element**
- Add any span element with the **class** for the FaceBook Icon.

Comment: I just tried it and could not get it to work perfectly? Can you send me the code you want me to use/try?

Comment: You already had it in your code successfully @tom. But still you can try with **few Styles**    `<button class="btn btn-lg" style="background-color:#3b5998; color:white;"><span class="fa fa-facebook mr-2"></span> Sign in with Facebook</button>`

Comment: Thx mate! it worked! I got made the button bigger in the width, but now I want to have the F from Facebook to be on the beginning and the text in the middle,but I got the text in the middle but the F is also next to it and not on the beginning of the line. @kingmaker

Comment: What width you need to change, buddy @tom?

Comment: I edited the question @kingmaker , I would love the result to be just like the second image in the question but with the text in the middle.

Comment: Btw I just saw that your code isnt working for me because I need the onclick and the php code @kingmaker

Comment: Add the **`onclick="window.location = '<?php echo $loginURL ?>';"`** to my `<button>` element........ Just simple

Comment: Yeahh I already figured that out :3 , the only thing is still that I want the F on the left and the text in the middle but if I add the text-align:left code on the button element it puts everything on the left .. so also the text.

Comment: Wrap the text **"login with Facebook"** within a **`<span style="padding-left:5rem;padding-right:5rem;">`** element and add equal Left&right padding to it......

Comment: **<button onclick="window.location = '<?php echo $loginURL ?>';" class="btn btn-md" style="background-color:#3b5998; color:white; width:100%;">
                <span class="fa fa-facebook mr-2"></span> Sign in with Facebook
            </button>** this is what I got now but I dont care anymore about where the text is but the onclick doesnt work or something, because I can click on it but I its not working

Comment: Inspect the element to find if the **PHP** has correctly echoed out....

Comment: There is no message

Comment: I put the code I am using atm in the question, I also showed the code that does work but is not looking the way I want it too

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

First of all you have to include font-awesome library in your code by typing

`<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css' />`

and then use font-awesome class for icons.

```
<button onclick="window.location = '<?php echo $loginURL ?>';"
  class="btn btn-block btn-social" value="Login met Facebook">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> Login with Facebook
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The glyphicon `btn-facebook` does not exist in the Bootstrap Library. 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/

Use e.g `facebook-square` from: http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Comment: Thx! Now I get the image in front of it but now the color of the button is gone some kind of white color and not the facebook color anymore.. how to fix that?

Comment: [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334851/change-the-color-of-glyphicons-to-blue-in-some-but-not-at-all-places-using-boot)