# How to change color of bootstrap glyphicon?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change bootstrap glyphicon color to "yellow" because current color is showing in white that looks like Delete button. How can i change color of `glyphicon-folder-close` or use any other glyphicon that display folder image better ?

main.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" ng-click="serverFiles()" style="margin-left: 10px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span></button>
```

Comment: `.glyphicon-folder-close { color: yellow}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use color

```
 <button type="button" 
      class="btn btn-info btn-lg" ng-click="serverFiles()"
      style="margin-left: 10px; color:#FF0000;">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span></button>
```

But remember that it is desirable to avoid the use of inline style  is better use  classes or references based on external css configuration items

```
 <button type="button" 
      class="btn btn-info btn-lg mybtn-blue" ng-click="serverFiles()"
      style="margin-left: 10px;">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span></button>
```

edn for external  css

```
.mybtn-blue {
   color: blue;
}
```

Comment: There is no property `text-color`

Comment: `text-color` should be `color`

Comment: @scaisEdge please do not guide the questioner to write inline styles...that not the correct way. try to add custom class to implement the styles...

Comment: With 30k rep I'm surprised you care about unfair downvotes still.

Comment: Do follow as @Morpheus have the above answer like .glyphicon-folder-c‌​lose { color: yellow}

Comment: @vignesh  . I agree with you about whether to avoid the use of styles in line .. but in this case OP already has an inline style .. anyway I'll put the recommendation in response.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i will remove inline styling.

Answer (score 17):

You can also change the icon/text by adding to the class "text-success" for green, "text-danger" for red etc. This will change the color of the icon itself.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd text-success"></span>
```

Also this has been answered here.

[Change the color of glyphicons to blue in some- but not at all places using Bootstrap 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334851/change-the-color-of-glyphicons-to-blue-in-some-but-not-at-all-places-using-boot)

Answer (score 3):

Use the following HTML code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" ng-click="serverFiles()" style="margin-left: 10px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close yellow"></span></button>
```

And the css code

```
.yellow {
    color: #FFCA28;
}
```

here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/S3R23/1217/

Comment: This is better clean looks seamless

Answer (score 2):

You can change color of the icon by directly specifying color name, however this will only apply to targeted icon.

```
<a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"  style="color: red; font-size: 20px"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the color, do this:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" style="color:#ffff00"></span>
```

Just edit the span tag in your code to the one above, making your code to look like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" ng-click="serverFiles()" style="margin-left: 10px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" style="color:#ffff00"></span></button>
```

Comment: This link will also help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070322/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3s-glyphicons-to-white

Answer (score 0):

You can change glyphicon color to any value. see below given example

```
<span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon form-control-feedback glyphicon-ok"></span>
```

//css

```
 .glyphicon.form-control-feedback.glyphicon-ok{
  color: #20032d !important;  
}
```