# Adding icon in data-loading-text in Rails submit_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:
`<%= submit_tag t('submit'), class: "btn btn-primary", id: "email_submitbutton", "data-loading-text" => "<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Processing Order" %>`

The icon tag in `data-loading-text` is processed as pure text by Rails.

I have tried using `data {...}` to wrap around it, but no change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `disable_with` option and using a button.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/submit_tag
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/button_tag

The reason for html not working in a submit tags is that they're turned into HTML input tag with the type submit.

```
<%= submit_tag "<p>Hi</p>" %>

<input type="submit" value="<p>Hi</p>">
```

[Rails 3 Submit Tag + html_safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077748/rails-3-submit-tag-html-safe)

```
<%= button_tag t('submit'), class: "btn btn-primary", id: "email_submitbutton", data: { disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Processing Order".html_safe } %>
```

Also, I highly suggesting using a Font-Awesome gem.

https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass

This is cool because it means you don't need to hand write HTML in you're Ruby code.

Comment: I tried your code, but it still doesn't work. The icon is still treated as text. Your method may only work on button tag not submit_tag. I have found a reference to your method at: https://gorails.com/episodes/button-loading-animations-with-jquery-ujs

Comment: You should use a button, as this will also post your form. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077748/rails-3-submit-tag-html-safe

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative way to achieve the same effect as Bootstrap's `data-loading-text` (changing text in button when clicked).

I changed `data-loading-text` to `disable_with` and change `submit_tag` with `button_tag`:

`<%= button_tag t('submit'), class: "btn btn-primary", id: "email_submitbutton", data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Processing Order".html_safe} %>`

It works as expected